# How to check from commandline if sudo authentication failed?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sudo

I was making a graphical front end to `sudo` for myself in bash scripting. Using something like `gksudo` is not an option for me, because the OS that I use doesn't provide one.

I designed it this way-

```bash
#!/bin/bash

sudo -S $@ <<< $(/usr/lib/gtkdialog/box_passwd "$USER password" "Enter password" 2>/dev/null)

STATUS=$?
if [ $STATUS -eq 127 ]; then
    /usr/lib/gtkdialog/box_splash -bg red -fg white -timeout 5 -text "sudo not found!"
    exit 1
fi

while [ $STATUS -ne 0 ]; do
    sudo -S $@ <<< $(/usr/lib/gtkdialog/box_passwd "$USER password" "Authentication failed! Please retry" 2>/dev/null)
    export STATUS=$?
done
```

(Note that `/usr/lib/gtkdialog/box_passwd` and `/usr/lib/gtkdialog/box_splash` are specific to this OS).

It works if I remove the while loop. But then the program would ask for the password only once, even if it was wrong. But currently, the while loop many a times doesn't end, because even if authentication is correct, `sudo` may also return `1` if the program it runs is not found or the program returns `1`.

So how can I make this code run the while loop only if authentication for `sudo` is failed, and not other times when `sudo` returns `1`?

**EDIT:** Just to make it clear, `/usr/lib/gtkdialog/box_passwd` is used here as graphical program to prompt the user for his/her password, which `/usr/lib/gtkdialog/box_passwd` passes to its `stdout` (prints to its `stdout`). `/usr/lib/gtkdialog/box_splash` is a program which just creates a new window and show some specific message

Answer (score 1):

In some OSes, the man page for sudo specifies which error messages would come from `sudo`. If your OS does that, you can grep stderr for these messages.

Otherwise, `sudo` isn't very helpful in that department, but if your usage of `sudo` is simple (no fancy configuration in `/etc/sudoers`, and no specific commands are configured to be allowed by `sudo`), then you can just do something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo -S true <<< $(/usr/lib/gtkdialog/box_passwd "$USER password" "Enter password" 2>/dev/null)

export STATUS=$?
if [ $STATUS -eq 127 ]; then
    /usr/lib/gtkdialog/box_splash -bg red -fg white -timeout 5 -text "sudo not found!"
    exit 1
fi

while [ $STATUS -ne 0 ]; do
    sudo -S true <<< $(/usr/lib/gtkdialog/box_passwd "$USER password" "Authentication failed! Please retry" 2>/dev/null)
    STATUS=$?
done

sudo "$@"
```

Namely, you don't run the command, you just run a dummy command (`true` in this case, which never fails).
In the default configuration, `sudo` remembers you for a few minutes.

So if you run `sudo "$@"` immediately after `sudo true` succeeded, `sudo` wouldn't ask you for a password in order to run the actual command.

Comment: Ok, so this can be done, until I know `true` is not the 'only' application provided the access to run as root without password. So basically I'd have to check that `true` is not permitted to run as root automatically, right? I'd also take a look at `grep`, might be a better solution that way.